# the page on which the app was exited should be shown when the app is opened again in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter. I need the app to show the last page that was selected before the app was closed. I tried a lot of things but have not solved it yet. I tried to store the current page into a location and to display that page when the app opens, but it ended up being an error.

Answer (score 0):

In flutter app all of data are storing in RAM while app is open, but when app is closes system erases all data. So, you must store data on the server or on the physical memory of device. You can use **sqflite** package or use **shared preferences** for storing data on the device.